# Azure IoT Edge: referencing certificates in config.yaml file

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

For testing purposes I'm trying to install certificates on my Edge Device (raspberry Pi) and following the Microsoft article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-manage-device-certificates

I create the test certifacates using this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-test-certificates#prerequisites and then I copy the 3 required files over to the raspberry pi into a folder called "certs",

After I copy over the required certifcates I update the config.yaml file with the file locations and restart iotedge but iotedge does not start up properly ie I don't see the modules load up and run

I'm not very familiar working in Linux so thinking that the issue could lie in 2 places currently:

1. My file URI is not formed correctly and so iotedge is not picking them up. How can I verify whether the below is correct?
2. iotedge does not have read access to the directory holding the certs. How do I make sure that iotedge has read access to the directory (ie certs)?

```
certificates:
  device_ca_cert: "file:///home/pi/certs/iot-edge-device-identity-edgedevice-pi-full-chain.cert.pem"
  device_ca_pk: "file:///home/pi/certs/iot-edge-device-EdgeCATestCert.key.pem"
  trusted_ca_certs: "file:///home/pi/certs/azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path names need to be in Linux format as in:

```
device_ca_cert: "/home/pi/certs/iot-edge-device-identity-edgedevice-pi-full-chain.cert.pem"
```

And yes you will need to make sure the user iotedge can read them.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll check if this is an alternative but In the end I was able to get it working with the file paths I had above after a fresh install of the IoT edge runtime.